# CF - Set Focus to a specific control

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, focus

I have a Form that has a panel with some textBoxes and checkBox that is outside the panel.
Every time the Form is loaded the checkBox has focus.

I have put en event handler when form loads and tried to set focus on first textbox instead having it on the checkbox.

```
this.Activated += new EventHandler(form_Activated);
```

in the method i try to set the focus on the first textbox in the panel

```
        private void form_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.parametersPanel.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            this.parametersPanel.Focus();
            (this.parametersPanel.Controls[0]).Focus();
        }
    }
```

This does not work, can some1 help me pls?

Comment: You could change TabIndex if that doesn't destroy navigation of course but if I read you correctly it sounds like that is what is currently messed up.

Comment: @no9 - I didn't have the same issue as you, but I was having some trouble finding where to add the code to call the Focus() method. Your sample code helped me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the focus directly on the textbox instead of using panel's controls index.

Comment: parametersPanel is loaded dynamicly. I dont have a property referencing the controls in the pannel ...

Answer (score 1):

In desing mode, select your control and set it's tabindex to 0

Comment: i did that. It does not help ! I tried setting parametersPanel tabIndex to 0 and i also tried setting tabIndex to the controls that get dynamically loaded to the panel. I think the problem is setting focus to a control that is within another control.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1:

Put this in the form's load event:

```
this.ActiveControl = myTextBox;
```

---

### Option 2:

Put this in the form's load event:

```
this.Show();
myTextBox.Focus();
```

Focus() will not work until the TextBox is visible.

Comment: It does not appear that `ActiveControl` is supported on the Compact Framework.

Comment: @reirab Thanks. I didn't know that. Option 2 should still work for any framework, though -- as long as the object can be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Activated` try `Shown`

Comment: What do you mean by that. Activated event works fine ... as will probably also Shown. The problem i have is setting the focus to the control inside panel.

Answer (score 0):

Yoc can use the solution provided by Ahmet. Since you want the text box to have the focus...setting the tab index to zero will do that.

Also you can use the textbox'e focus method to set the focus, in the form's load event....